# How to lock focus on popup in wpf

Tags: wpf, popup, focus

Is there any way in WPF to lock the focus on the popup so that we cannot set focus on other elements on the view?

I have a popup and have bound it to the IsOpen property of the ViewModel:

```
    <Popup x:Name="myPopup" 
           Width="{Binding ElementName=RootLayout, Path=ActualWidth}"
           Height="350"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=RootLayout}"
           Placement="Center"
           IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen}"
           StaysOpen="True"
           AllowsTransparency="True">

        /// Popup elements

    </Popup>
```

It works fine and when the IsOpen property in the ViewModel is set to true the popup shows up. but the problem is when I press the tab button, the focus goes to the other elements on the view while I need it to say on the popup.

How can I do that please? any help is appreciated.

Comment: this is a complex issue, usually it solves by defining focus scopes, but it would be difficult to answer the same without looking at your full xaml, perhaps a working sample.

Comment: Why not use modal `Window` instead of `Popup`?